# ServerAlias Name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add an exception such as not xx.com in the server alias for httpd.conf.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: `ServerAlias` doesn't do that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias

Downvote. One of the very first examples in the mod_rewrite docs is for detecting a non-matching host. Read the manual first:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#url

Comment: @pekka <virtual host.....>
ServerAlias *x* !x2

Comment: @Jean I still don't understand why you wouldn't simply *not mention* x2 to exclude it? Maybe edit a real-world example into the question?

Comment: @Jean then don't mention x2. Problem solved :) I think @cecil's answer is on the right track

Comment: @pekka if I add *x* then I need to exclude x2 :) get the point

Comment: @jean nope, I still don't :) Can you make a real-world example and edit it into your question?

Comment: Supposing someone types in xxx.com (*x*) I redirect it to sex.com, now if they type in x2.com I want to filter that out (!x2)

Comment: @Jean then you need to configure your `VirtualHosts` so that address won't be served at all.

Comment: @pekka There seems to be a problem there too, I need to redirect this *x2* to a different url :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, ServerAlias only matches a single domain at a time. The only way to add an exception would be to not ServerAlias that domain.

If you don't want a VirtualHost to match xx.com, then don't put `ServerAlias xx.com` in the VirtualHost, and you should be fine?

I'm guessing that's not your problem, because that's pretty obvious, so let me guess on other things you might be asking about:

If you're asking for a way to do a wildcard ServerAlias that will match multiple domains, you should probably be using mod_rewrite instead of relying on Apache's VirtualHost limited parsing. It is very powerful and regex-based and it can handle all sorts of wildcards and patterns.

If, on the other hand, you want to add an exception to a particular URL on xx.com and point just that URL at a different VirtualHost, that also can be done with mod_rewrite.

In short, look at mod_rewrite, and see if that can help you do what you need to do.

It also occurs to me that you may be confusing the behavior of the first VirtualHost. The first VirtualHost is **always** the default. If no other VirtualHost matches, the first will always be used for any domain that Apache receives. The only way to "exclude" a domain from the default VirtualHost is by adding its own, specific VirtualHost to capture it. In any case, mod_rewrite is probably going to be your friend here too.

Edit: Here is a snippet from my VirtualHost configuration, maybe this will help you understand what I'm telling you to do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # This is the default VirtualHost, because it is listed first.
    # All domain names that are not recognized elsewhere go here
    # automatically. All this VirtualHost does is to display a simple
    # HTML page informing users that no site exists at that address.

    # ServerName/Alias doesn't matter, because it's not a real vhost
    ServerName default-vhost.mysite.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nosite

    # In case someone goes to http://unknownsite.com/something/else.html
    # make sure they get the "no site" message, so redirect all URLs.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(..*) /index.html [NS]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This is my real website. Because it is listed second, it will ONLY
    # be accessible from hostnames listed as ServerName or ServerAlias

    ServerName mysite.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Long story short, web host has issues with .htaccess, else that was my best shot, now I need to do a exclude

Comment: So let me see if I understand. You have a VirtualHost that has `ServerAlias x.com`, but when you go to x2.com, you get the x.com VirtualHost?

Comment: I have ServerAlias *x* !x2
That is I do not want any redirect when it is !x2

Comment: @Jean this does not make any sense. Please come forward with a real world example, as requested repeatedly now.

Comment: You can't do that with ServerAlias. Remove the !x2. It won't work. What you need to do to exclude x2 is to add ANOTHER VirtualHost, and make that one have a `SeverName x2`. Then all VirtualHost requests for x2 will go there. That's the only way to exclude it from the default VirtualHost.

Comment: It will not since there is an "X" in x2, thats the problem when I add *x*, I need x2 to be filtered

Comment: You are incorrect. ServerAlias does NOT match wildcards, not in Apache (you are using Apache right?), unless it is the FIRST VIRTUALHOST, in which case it matches EVERYTHING, ALWAYS. You will need to add a SECOND VIRTUALHOST to fix this problem. I have added my example configuration to the answer, I hope that will help explain it.

Comment: ServerAlias does match wild cards, it works I am on centos, LAMP